# Is there a way to have "parallel" for loop in Django template tags?

Tags: django

So I have two models : `Question` and `Answer`, like below:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=False, default="")
```

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    number = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False, default="")
```

And what I want to do is display all questions and each corresponding answers. Like this:

> Q1. This is the first question
> A1. This is this user's first answer.
>
> Q2. This is the second question
> A2. This is this user's second answer.
> And so on..
>
> So I have my view like this:

```
def questionsAndAnswers(request):
    thisUser = User.objects.get(authuser_id=request.user.id)
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(authuser_id=request.user.id)  
    questions = Question.objects.filter(authuser_id=request.user.id)

    context = {
        'thisUser' : thisUser,
        'answers': answers,
        'questions' : questions,
    }
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

AND NOW I'M STUCK.
Apparently, I cannot have two nested for loops, like below (simplifed):

```
...
{% for q in questions %}
{% for a in answers %}
<div>Question : {{q.question}}</div>
<div>Answer : {{a.answer}}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

So I was wondering if there's a way to have "parallel" for loops in the template. How do I do this? 
I very much appreciate your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel loops (using `zip`) won't work properly either, since nothing guarantees the order of questions wrt answers, and there's no guarantee there's only one answer per question.

You could instead just use the [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) of the foreign key – and now that I'm at it, you should rename the `number` foreign key to `question` to make it make sense. (It points to a question after all, not a number.)

However (as revised via comments), that won't be effective here; it's better to just gather user answers and show them grouped by question. (The below code assumes `number` is `question`.)

- Note you don't need to look up the user again, or query by ID – querying by the `request.user` object will do.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def questionsAndAnswers(request):
    user_answers = Answer.objects.filter(authuser=request.user).prefetch_related('question')
    questions_and_answers = defaultdict(list)
    for answer in user_answers:
       questions_and_answers[answer.question].append(answer)

    context = {
        'questions_and_answers' : questions_and_answers,
    }
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

```
{% for q, answers in questions_and_answers.items %}
  <div>Question : {{q.question}}</div>
  {% for a in answers %}
     <div>Answer : {{a.answer}}</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh, I ran into a problem. The thing is, the ```Question``` model does not have a ```authuser``` field, because the questions are given by the service itself, like quiz. So the ```Question.objects.filter(authuser=request.user)``` part won't work :(

Comment: Okay, so there's no error, but I'm not getting anything on the screen. So I tried ```{{questions_and_answers}}``` to see what's going on, then I got this : ```defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {<Question:  first question>: [<Answer: first answer>], <Question: second question>: [<Answer: second answer], ... ```. the data inside are random questions and answers that I put in for testing. So am I supposed to get this result for ```{{questions_and_answers}}```? Thanks :)

Comment: I did it. So in the value part of  ```context```, I tried ```dict(questions_and_answers)``` instead of ```questions_and_answers```, then everything worked fine. Thanks a lot :)